Django: Add values from dict Queryset
I have this entry monitoring table that has multiple dates and time values. I wanted to get total number of entry every month, that has multiple entry every day per user.
I used this line:
stats=EntryMonitoring.objects.filter(student_id=user).annotate(month=TruncMonth('date')).values('month').annotate(total=Count('id')) 
The results is:
<QuerySet [{'month': datetime.date(2024, 3, 1), 'total': 25}, {'month': datetime.date(2024, 4, 1), 'total': 1}]>
I view the data by using this {% for obj in stats %}{{ obj.total }}{% endfor %}
So I got 251. I want to add the total values like 25 and 1, that would be a total of 26 entry for the year. And for 251, how should I seperate the value? Cause I will make a graph for this total values by monthly.

"total of 26 entry for the month" but the 25 and 1 is for separate months. Do you just want the complete total regardless of the month? Or do you want something like a running count (25 for the first month, 26 for the next, etc.)?

@AbdulAzizBarkat Yes, cause I'll be needing this for annual or daily summaries. And how do I seperate the total per month?

Yes to what? Please be clear. [Edit] your question with the clarifications on what you want.

Looking at your question, I believe what you want is to increment the total cumulative of your monthly count stats right — 1 + 25 = 26 in your queryset of your ListView?
Here is an updated version of your code, and how you can achieve that mate with the comments I wrote for you to understand me clearly.

import datetime
from django.db.models import Count
from django.db.models.functions import TruncMonth
from django.views import generic

# since I didn't see your view, I assume you are using the View class
# However, you can replace this view name with your own name

class MonthlyStatListView(generic.ListView):

    template_name = 'your template url here'
    ordering = 'id'
    context_name = "if any, write your context name"


    def get_queryset(self):

        # your code
        queryset = EntryMonitoring.objects.filter(student_id=user).\
                       annotate(month=TruncMonth('date')).values('month').\
                       annotate(total=Count(self.ordering)) 

        # assumed results - and your goal is to add up the cummulative total in each month
        stats = [
                {'month': datetime.date(2024, 3, 1), 'total': 
            25}, 
               {'month': datetime.date(2024, 4, 1), 'total': 
              1}
                
                ]

        cumulative_total = 0

        #Iterate through the list of dictionaries in order via forloop
        for entry in  queryset[::1]:
            # add the ‘total’ value to the cumulative total for each dictionary, 
            cumulative_total += entry['total']

            #  updated list of dictionaries of the entry
            entry['cumulative_total'] = cumulative_total

        print(queryset)
        # the print statement will return this below as your answer, which you can now use on your template

        # [{'month': datetime.date(2024, 3, 1), 'total': 25, 'cumulative_total': 25}, {'month': datetime.date(2024, 4, 1), 'total': 1, 'cumulative_total': 26}]

        return queryset



NB: If you are not familiar with Django Class-Based Views, kindly check it out here on the documentation. Goodluck mate.

Thank you! This surely helped! Now I'm making graphs using this values.
